# Crate DB with Nginx Binding

Tags: json, nginx, cratedb

I was wondering is there a way to bind Nginx web server with CrateDB Backend to receive JSON data over https and store them in the CrateDB.So basically CrateDB should run as an appserver with nginx binding. The longer route would be to use php or python code to do this, but if there is an easier option available to do this it would be great. If any of you have been able to do this please let me know.
The direct HTTP binding via REST API is a no go as it does not support HTTPS at this point in time. let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

putting nginx as proxy in front of crate (and write an application in lua) is straight forward: https://crate.io/a/readonly-crate-with-nginx-and-lua/

Comment: thats interesting! but It says its readonly support since v0.55, my requirement is to insert json objects into crateDB, is this currently not supported? thanks!